# Excel formula with 2 logic conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to a logical condition on 2 cells. If first cell has a value greater that zero, then if second cell is equal to zero return "Failed" or if second cell is greater than 0 return "Good". If first cell is equal to zero than return "N/A".

I am currently using:

```
=IF(V278>0,"GOOD",(IF(Y278=0,"FAILED","N/A")))
```

but it is not working as intended.

Comment: You should be able to cobble something together using spreadsheet functions like `IF()` and `AND()` and `OR()`. What have you tried?

Comment: I ve tried to nest  two IF statement

Comment: If you edit the question and provide the formula that you tried, it might help others get a better idea of what you are trying to do and where it is going wrong.

Comment: =IF(V278>0,"GOOD",(IF(Y278=0,"FAILED","N/A")))

Answer (score 0):

Change the nesting so that the `"N/A"` is the alternative for the first condition rather than the second:

```
=IF(V278 > 0, IF(Y278 = 0,"FAILED","GOOD"),"N/A")
```

seems like it should implement what you are trying to do.

Comment: Did you try replacing the commas by semicolons? If this does not help, please tell me the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to first make a complete list of the possibilities you might have:

```
        |  cell2=0 | cell2>0 |
--------+----------+---------+
cell1=0 |      N/A |     N/A |
--------+----------+---------+
cell1>0 |   FAILED |    GOOD |
--------+----------+---------+
```

Is this correct?

In that case, I'll advise you to start here:

```
If Cell1=0 
  then "N/A"
  else if Cell2=0
       then "FAILED"
       else "GOOD"
```

Now, turn this into a formula (Cell1 being V278 and Cell2 being Y278):

```
If(V278=0;"N/A";IF(Y278=0;"FAILED";"GOOD"))
```

Does this work?

Comment: Yes that's correct, but excel is not excepting your formula